# Filtering a json object using Swift's Map api and Objective-c's valueForKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, json, swift

Given http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

For simplicity here is an abridged version of the json

```
var userDict: [[String, String]]?  <-- String json converts into foundation and saved here

// The Json
[{
  "address" : {
    "geo" : {
      "lat" : "-37.3159"
    }
  }
}]
```

I am trying to get an array of lat which is the latitude of of the geographical point of an address.  I have two choices, swift or objective-c

I can get an array of lat using the old valueForKeyPath: method

```
var keypathLatitude: [String] = (userDict! as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("address.geo.lat") as! [String] // Objective-c api
```

Which would give me ["-37.3159"] which is an array with one element.
But I am having difficulty doing it with swift's map api

```
var mapLatitude: [String] = userDict!.map({$0["address"]?["geo"]["lat"] as! String}) // <-- Does not like this.  But I want ["-37.3159"] as a result.
```

**UPDATE**

```
var mapLatitude: [String] = userDict!.map({$0["address"]?["geo"]??["lat"] as! String})
```

Using mattdaw's suggestion I added another '?'.  It did not work.  Oddly enough, when I added '??' it appears to work as desired.  .... but Why?  The '??' is the nil coalescing operator is it not?

btw, I'm doing this is playgrounds

Answer (score 1):

With pure Swift objects, optional chaining works:

```
let users = [ [ "address": [ "geo": [ "lat": "-37.3159" ] ] ] ]
let lats = users.map { $0["address"]?["geo"]?["lat"] }
println(lats)
```

... but when you're dealing with the result of parsing JSON through NSJSONSerialization, it gets ugly. Check out SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON) for more background.

Comment: I updated my answer to use '?' operator. map({$0["address"]?["geo"]?["lat"] does not work.  but this does: map({$0["address"]?["geo"]??["lat"].  That SwiftyJson looks really neat!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify type to return and cast each elemnt as Dictionary.(Xcode 6.3.1)

```
let mapLatitude = userDict.map { p -> String in
    let wAddress = p[ "address" ] as! [ String: AnyObject ]
    let wGeo = wAddress[ "geo" ] as! [ String: AnyObject ]
    return wGeo[ "lat" ] as! String
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't like to be verbose

```
    var mapLatitude = userDict.map( { $0[ "address" ]![ "geo" ]![ "lat" ]! } )
```

was the answer.

Comment: Very True.  It certainly CAN be broken down to that level of detail, but it seems overly verbose (and I thought Objective-c was the verbose one!)